# how to reset a value of a textarea if another input has value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to JS I have input and textarea I want to reset the textarea's value, if input is changed

```
<!doctype html>
<HTML lang="en">
<HEAD>
<META charset="utf-8">
<META name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<TITLE>Hello, world!</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<INPUT type="text">
<TEXTAREA>AAAA</TEXTAREA>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this real quick with Jquery as follows:

```js
$('input').change(function() {
  $('textarea').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text">
<br/><br/>
<textarea>AAA</textarea>
```

You can replace `.change` with `.keyup` if you want the `textarea` value to reset immediately `input` is typed on.

input event triggers:
`.change`: Fires the moment the value of `input` is changed or clicked out of.
`.keyup`: Fires when a key is released on `input`.
`.keydown`: Fires when a key is pressed down on `input`.

Answer (score -2):

Modify your HTML code as follows:

```
    <!doctype html>
<HTML lang="en">
<HEAD>
<META charset="utf-8">
<META name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<TITLE>Hello, world!</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <INPUT type="text" id="inputField1" onInput="document.getElementById('textarea1').innerHTML = '';">
    <TEXTAREA id="textarea1" >aaa</TEXTAREA>


</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: You should not use unsafe inline on* attribute handlers. Use `addEventListener()` instead. JS, same for CSS should never be inline, but in their respective files or tags.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).